# Dequeue Reusable Cell crashes when calling dequeued cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I am attempting to have a table view that lists multiple things and allows a user to go through and select multiple cells with checkboxes. My code works up until a certain point, the problem is that the app crashes with the following error

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

whenever I call the following code

`swift let currentCell = recommendToFriendTableView.cellForRow(at: selectedRow[i]) as? RecommendToFriendsTableViewCell`

Here is the method where we set up the cells

```swift
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if (tableView == self.friendListTableView) {


            let cell:  FriendListTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FriendListCell") as! FriendListTableViewCell

            let rowNumber = (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row
            var name = ""
            if searchActive {
                name = filtered[rowNumber]
            }
            else {
                name = names[rowNumber]
            }
            cell.friendNameLabel.text = name
            cell.friendNameLabel.backgroundColor = tableViewBgColor
            cell.friendNameLabel.textColor = textColor
            cell.recommendToFriendButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
            cell.recommendToFriendButton.layer.borderColor = tableViewBgColor.cgColor
            cell.recommendToFriendButton.layer.cornerRadius = 6
            cell.recommendToFriendButton.backgroundColor = buttonBgColor
            cell.backgroundColor = tableViewBgColor
            //set target for buttons
            cell.recommendToFriendButton.tag = rowNumber
            cell.recommendToFriendButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(recommendToFriendButtonClicked), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)

            return cell
        }
        else {
            let cell: RecommendToFriendsTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RecommendToFriendsCell") as! RecommendToFriendsTableViewCell
            let rowNumber = (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row
            // set the content view background color
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = tableViewBgColor
            // set the text color
            cell.nameLabel.textColor = textColor
            var dict_friend = NSMutableDictionary()
            if searchActive {
                dict_friend = filteredFriendsArray[rowNumber]
            }
            else {
                dict_friend = friendsArray[rowNumber]
            }

            let name = dict_friend["name"] as! String
            cell.nameLabel.text = name
            let friendUID = dict_friend["uid"] as! String
            cell.friendID = friendUID
            let imageAddress = dict_friend["photo"] as? String

            if imageAddress != "unavailable" && imageAddress != nil && imageAddress != ""{



                //Swift forces us to wrap strings as optional to use them in logic
                if let imageURL = imageAddress as String? {

                    //Swift forces us to wrap strings as optional to use them in logic
                    if let image = imageURL as String? {

                        //We convert the string into a URL and get the image
                        let url = URL(string: image)
                        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

                            if error != nil {
                                print(error!)
                                return
                            }

                            //We create a new async thread to download and update the image
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                //imageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                                cell.photoImageView.image = UIImage(data:data!)

                            }
                        }).resume()
                    }



                } else {
                    cell.photoImageView!.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder-profile-male.png")
                }

            } else {
                cell.photoImageView!.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder-profile-male.png")
            }

            cell.checkBoxImageView.image = cell.checkBoxImageView.image!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
            cell.checkBoxImageView.tintColor = textColor
            // Style the profile photo to show in a circle
            cell.photoImageView.layer.borderWidth = 0
            cell.photoImageView.layer.borderColor = tableViewBgColor.cgColor
            // Set cornerRadius = a square UIImageView frame size width / 2
            // In our case, UIImageView height = width = 60 points
            cell.photoImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 30
            cell.photoImageView.clipsToBounds = true
            cell.selectionStyle = .none // to prevent cells from being "highlighted"
            return cell
        }
    }
```

This is the method where we interact with them. The crash happens on a cellForRow call for a cell that is out of view (aka dequeued)

```swift
  var firstFriendName: String = ""
        var numberOfFriends = 0
        if let selectedRow = recommendToFriendTableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
            numberOfFriends = selectedRow.count
            for i in 0..<selectedRow.count {
                let currentCell = recommendToFriendTableView.cellForRow(at: selectedRow[i]) as! RecommendToFriendsTableViewCell
                let friendID = currentCell.friendID
                idList.append(",\(friendID)")
            }
            let firstSelectedCell = recommendToFriendTableView.cellForRow(at: selectedRow[0]) as! RecommendToFriendsTableViewCell
            firstFriendName = firstSelectedCell.nameLabel.text!
```

After about a day of experimenting, I've yet to figure out the actual problem (other than the observation that it appears to be in regards to calling a dequeued cell)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: check your cell outlets

Comment: I had a similar issue once and solved it by using data from the underlying data source instead of the cells. Not sure if you can use that approach.

Comment: Which variable is nil and at what line? And why are you calling `cellForRowAt` directly? Whatever you are trying to do when calling `cellForRowAt` can most likely be re-written better without calling that function.

Comment: @matt selectedRow is defined in the second block of code shown. it is ```recommendToFriendTableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows``` where recommendToFriendTableView is a UITableView

Comment: your content may be scrolling when running this code ?

Comment: @AgRizzo it would seem based on the error and the code that when the cell is out of view, trying to return the cell seems to return nil. Do you have any ideas on how this can be re-written better without calling that function?

Comment: In your code, get the `friendId` from whatever the data source is (presumably an array) Same with the `firstFriendName`. There should be no reason for you to need the cell when you have access to the underlying data source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When this line

```
 let currentCell = recommendToFriendTableView.cellForRow(at: selectedRow[i]) as! RecommendToFriendsTableViewCell
```

crashes this means you access a non-visble cell so  either use

```
 if let currentCell = recommendToFriendTableView.cellForRow(at: selectedRow[i]) as? RecommendToFriendsTableViewCell { }
```

or better  use the dataSource array of the table to get the data that you want to gran wrongly from the cell